# how to call Activity in TabBars in android

Tags: android

hi all
i need some help from you guys.. 
well here's the description

Guys is it possible that we make some Tab Bars in our Android and then there are only two tab bars. one for the View and second for the Help.
now is it possible that when i click on View Tab then it open an activity named "List" and when we click any list item then it should change the activity from "list" to "Wotever" remaining in the same Tab.

please guide me guys... 
and help through some tutorial..

Thnks a bunch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
for this you have to use ActivityGroup

check this link for nested tabActivty

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/
 thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just start the activity Wotever from the list:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,Wotever.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i did this but it gives me Exception that activity can not be started.. i even Put activity Tag in my Manifest File but still Dealing with Exception..